# T and F on some discrete math concepts

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was studying and these questions came up on a review guide on the inter webs, but could was wondering if I was correct on them.

1.Let $B$ $\subset$ $A$ and $f$ : $B$  $\subset$ $A$ be a 1-1 and onto, then $B$ = $A$ (Sets A and B can be either finite or infinite.)  $T?$ **WRONG** 
(that means they are the same set correct?)**FALSE**

2.The spanning tree for any given graph is always unique. F?**RIGHT**
(Googled it but I'm getting mix answers)

3.($A$ $\cup$ $B$ $\subset$ $A$ $\cup$ $C$) then $B$ $\subset$ $C$. T?**WRONG**
(I can see it work when I drew a Venn Diagram, but I'm not sure if there are more possibilities in drawing them)**FALSE**

4.Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets and $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Then if $f(x \cap y)$ = $f(x) \cap f(y)$ for all nonempty subsets $X$ and $Y$ of A, then f must be 1-1. T? **WRONG**
(I know that if $A\rightarrow$$B$ is 1-1 that it is true, but IDK if it MUST be 1-1)
**FALSE**

5.A simple graph G with 13 vertices has 4 vertices of degree 4, 3 vertices of degree 3 and 6 vertices of degree 1, then G must be a tree. T?**WRONG**
(Not sure sure how to figure this out)
**FALSE**

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Oh sorry about that, will fix her up

Comment: oh so that means bijection could happen ex {1,2,3..} and {10,20,30...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** It is true for **finite** sets but false in general. For example $A= \mathbb Z, B=2 \mathbb Z$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$.

**2** Is false. You can always create spanning trees by erasing edges from cycles, as long as you start with connected graphs, and you can erase any edge, as long as it is in a cycle. Thus, if you create a spanning three, then start again and erase one of the edges you have in the first spanning three, your second spanning tree is different.

**3** Is false. Simplest counterexample, take $B=A$ and $C \subset A$ but $C \neq A$.

**4** Assume there exists $a \neq b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Set $x= \{a \}\ ,;\, y=\{b \}$.

**5** As pointed by another poster, the handshaking lemma fails. In general, when you have many vertices, even if the degrees are compatible with the Handshaking lemma, and the degrees are the "right" degrees, the degree down't imply a tree.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you elaborate on number 4.  I know the converse is true, but I'm not quite grasping, the contraposition

Comment: @Yummytree If $x=\{ a \}$ and $y = \{ b \}$, with $a \neq b$  then $f(x \cap y)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. But $f(x)\cap f(y)= \{f(a) \} \cap \{f(b) \}$ which is the emptyset if and only if $f(a) \neq f(b)$.

Comment: ah, thank you for your help! So the answer is false (Just to make sure)

Answer (score 0):

For 2, consider a square. You can construct a spanning tree by removing any one edge, so there are four.

For 3, a very trivial counterexample is $A = \{1,2\}, B = \{1\}, C = \{2\}$, but you could find more "interesting" ones.

For 4, by contraposition, if $f$ is not 1-1, there are $x, y$ such that $x \ne y$ and $f(x) = f(y)$. This makes the given property false.

For 5, the sum of the degrees is odd, this is a problem...